# How can I place legen in the right upper corner above the chart?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

How can I place the legend in the right upper corner above the chart?
I was able to place it in the right upper corner but the whole right side of the graph shrink . I want, that the top shrink. Here the image, so you can see what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the option

```
 legend: { show:true, placement:'outside', location: 'n' }
```

and then you can set the margins on the legend using the marginTop, marginLeft, etc. properties or via CSS margin styling of the .jqplot-table-legend class (for exemple to move it to the position in the image that you provided you could `margin-left:50%`